# Cant remove all chars from a string before a "special one"

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, char

I tried coding a complete decimal to binary converter, which worked just fine and now I want to remove the unnecessary 0s from my output String, but it doesnt remove all of the 0s and I have no idea why.

Here is my code :

```
public class Converter {

private static final int[] ARRAY = {16348,8192,4096,2048,1024,512,256,128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1};

public static String toBinary(int number) {

    String output = new String();
    int number2 = number;

    for (int i=0; i<ARRAY.length ; i++) {

        if (number2 - ARRAY[i] >= 0) {
            output += "1";
            number2 -= ARRAY[i];
        }
        else {
            output += "0";
        }
    }

    boolean sorted = false;
    int i = 0 ;

    while (sorted == false) {

        if (output.charAt(i) == '0') {
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(output);
            temp.deleteCharAt(i);
            output = temp.toString();
            i ++;
        }
        else{
            sorted = true;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

}

Comment: When I use the binary for 7 for example it only removes the first 6 0s from the String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the variable `i` is pointing to a wrong location. It's because after you remove the `0` at the `i`th you are incrementing `i`.

For example, take the string `00001` (a minified one in terms of number of bits)

When `i = 0`, after removing the `0` at index `i` we get `0001`. On incrementing `i` becomes `1`.
When `i = 1`, after removing the `0` at index `i`  we get `001`. On incrementing `i` becomes `2`.
(We have already skipped past the first 0).

Removing `i++` will do the trick. Still, your code does not work for input `0`. In your while loop, you still need to validate the index `i` and break the while loop by checking if `output` string is empty.

A simple solution would be to use `Integer.valueOf` as suggested in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49221813/4405757)

Or another one-liner would be:

```
String result = output.contains("1") ? output.substring(output.indexOf("1")) : "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use simpler solution to remove trailing zero's by parsing the output to `Integer` 
use this

```
int x = Integer.valueOf(output);
// if you wanted the output as string 
String val = String.valueOf(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is preferable that you don't add the leading zeroes in the first place.  Why create, then remove?  This method will not add leading zeroes until a one has been detected:

```
public static String toBinary(int number) {

    String output = new String();
    int number2 = number;

    boolean foundOne = false;
    for (int i=0; i<ARRAY.length ; i++) {

        if (number2 - ARRAY[i] >= 0) {
            output += "1";
            number2 -= ARRAY[i];
            foundOne = true;
        }
        else if (foundOne){
            output += "0";
        }
    }
    if (!foundOne)
        output = "0";

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is probably the one that makes the most sense to me as to how i should have done it. (I didnt mark it as best answer because it doesnt directly answer, why only 6 of the zeroes are removed)

Comment: I understand.  You still have the option to upvote it as useful.  Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "00010101"
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^0*", "")) 
// => 10101
```

This is a example using regex.
`^` means the expression should only match at the beginning of a string.
`0*`matches any string of characters that repeats `0` zero or more times